# Two mini pages side by side vertically aligned on top

Tags: minipage

I would like to have two mini pages side by side, vertically aligned on top.

The left hand mini page features a table, the right hand side simple text. Alas, the right mini page is a little lower compared to the left one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}%
%\hrule
\begin{tabular}{rl}
abc & def \\
abc & def \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}%
%\hrule
abc

def

ghi

jkl
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

If you comment in the two `\hrule` commands, they are on par. How come? What am I doing wrong?

BTW: if the table only features one line, the mini pages are on par, even without the `hrule` commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need

```
 \begin{tabular}[t]{rl}
```

Otherwise the baseline of the first line of the minipage goes through the *centre* of the tabular.

Comment: Thanks, this helped to have the first line of the table on par with the first line of the right mini page. If I encapsulate each of the two mini pages with `fbox{}`, the right frame is again a little lower, though the text lines remain on par. What's wrong this time?

Comment: no idea, fbox should not change the baseline alignment at all. You would have to reduce the width of the minipages (by 2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule) to make space for the rules and padding. Oh add a `\strut` to your line of text in the left frame to make sure the line has full height